# can't fetch user's interest(not likes) from facebook graph api V2.10

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want interests from the particular user when the user logged in from facebook in my application but facebook graph API doesn't support it from V2.2, so I want interests like tinder fetch from Facebook when you are log in through FB. Any thing which can help me to find user's interests will be appreciated.

Comment: all available fields and edges are listed in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user - if it´s not there, you can´t get it. tinder may still have the data in their database from earlier versions of the api, btw.

Comment: but still, new user's interests also fetched from facebook so m asking for any hack or algorithm which I can use? and I have read all docs from graph-API already. @luschn